# Retrieving Partition Properties Script from SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, xmla

I am attempting to catalogue a set of olap-cubes from a SQL Server DB. In the analysis services (SSMS), I can right click a measure_group/table, click partitions, properties, and then use "Script Action to New Query Window". This yields me a script with the various sources used to populate this measure_group.

In the interest of automation, I was wondering if one could retrieve this script through a query. The closest I've gotten is this:

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <RequestType>DISCOVER_PARTITION_STAT</RequestType>
    <Restrictions>
        <RestrictionList>
            <DATABASE_NAME>database_name</DATABASE_NAME>
            <CUBE_NAME>cube_name</CUBE_NAME>
            <MEASURE_GROUP_NAME>measure_group_name</MEASURE_GROUP_NAME>
            <PARTITION_NAME>partition_name</PARTITION_NAME>
        </RestrictionList>
    </Restrictions>
    <Properties>
        <PropertyList>
            <Catalog>database_name</Catalog>
            <Format>Tabular</Format>
        </PropertyList>
    </Properties>
</Discover>
```

However, the requirement to provide the Partition_Name as a restriction is problematic, because it differs from measure to measure, and would thus require manual entries, defeating the purpose of the script.

Is there a simple query that can be used to get the whole script, without needing to specify more than the database_name and measure_group?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    MGP.TMEASUREGROUP_NAME AS MeasureGroupName,
    MGP.TMEASUREGROUP_SOURCE AS MeasureGroupSource
FROM 
    $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUPS AS MGP
WHERE 
    MGP.CUBE_NAME = 'your cube'
    AND MGP.DATABASE_NAME = 'your db'
    AND MGP.TMEASUREGROUP_NAME = 'your measure group'
```

The `$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUPS` schema rowset provides metadata information about measure groups in SSAS. The `TMEASUREGROUP_SOURCE` column contains the script used to populate the measure group.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that did not work for me. I used this in the end:

SELECT *
FROM $system.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS;

And one of the fields had all of the queries.